# Sql Query to fetch invalid entries

Tags: mysql

I want a sql query to fetch invalid entries in ph_no such as entries which has text(a-z) or special characters or which are not 10 digit long or entries which are 10 digit long but has special character or text in it

```
I have used the following code
SELECT PH_NO FROM Table WHERE LENGTH(PH_NO)<=9
It is only fetching entries which are not 10 digit long but i want entries which are 10 digit long but contains text or special character as well
```

Comment: So what you've done so far?

Comment: Remember StackOverflow is not a 'do this for me' site. Please share your code and ask a specific question on your problem. Visit [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expresion in your where clause, you get when PH_NO length is less than 10, or when the length is 10 and is not in the regular expresion:

```
SELECT PH_NO 
FROM table1 
WHERE LENGTH(PH_NO)<=9 OR 
    (LENGTH(PH_NO)=10 AND PH_NO NOT REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{10}$')
```

Comment: Nearly. But I don't think this is quite what the OP is after

Comment: You might want to add the $? '[[:digit:]]+$' in case of decimal. i.e. 1.1 etc. and other special characters. Additionally no need to test for =10 just the OR NOT regexp. any values that is less than 10 will be covered by the first condition and the rest is for the regexp. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you achieving the specifics given by you

```
 SELECT PH_NO FROM Table WHERE LENGTH(convert(PH_NO,signed))!=10;
```

The conver() will return 1 or 0 if PH_NO contains any character, so if your 10 digit PH_NO will contain any invalid entry than this query will give the right output.

Comment: hmm I don't think this will work on leading zeros. '0000000001'.

Comment: Yes it will work  because no phone number starts with 0. For the given string ' '0000000001' it will return 1

Comment: He didn't mention that PH_NO is a phone number? Also, it is not a general rule.There could be area codes that starts with 0 from other countries.